# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException vs IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java

If we create a dummy `ArrayList` like below and call `get` method with `-1` and `1` as argument. Then we get the following `output`:

- For Test  Case 1 : It throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`
- For Test Case 2 : It throws `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

  ```
  List list = new ArrayList();
  list.get(-1); //Test Case 1
  list.get(1); // Test Case 2
  ```

Please explain the why there is difference between these two ?

Comment: One immediately-obvious difference is that `-1` will never be a valid index, whereas `1` will be (if a list has at least two entries).

Comment: *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException* is a subclass of **IndexOutOfBoundException** - the most important point. The other subclass is *StringIndexOutOfBoundsException*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an implementation detail of `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList` is backed by an array. An access to an array with a negative index throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so it doesn't have to be tested explicitly by the code of `ArrayList` class.

On the other hand, if you access the `ArrayList` with a non-negative index that is outside the range of the `ArrayList` (i.e. >= the size of the `ArrayList`), a specific check is performed in the following method, which throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
/**
 * Checks if the given index is in range.  If not, throws an appropriate
 * runtime exception.  This method does *not* check if the index is
 * negative: It is always used immediately prior to an array access,
 * which throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if index is negative.
 */
private void rangeCheck(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

This check is necessary since the supplied index may be a valid index of the backing array (if it is smaller than the current capacity of the `ArrayList`), so accessing the backing array with an index >= the `ArrayList`'s size will not necessarily throw an exception.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a sub-class of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, which means it is correct to say `ArrayList`'s `get` method throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for both negative indices and indices >= the size of the list.

Note that unlike `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for both negative and non-negative indices, since it is not backed by an array, so it cannot rely on an array to throw an exception for negative indices:

```
private void checkElementIndex(int index) {
    if (!isElementIndex(index))
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}

/**
 * Tells if the argument is the index of an existing element.
 */
private boolean isElementIndex(int index) {
    return index >= 0 && index < size;
}
```

Comment: @Eran- Sir Java docs says  if index is less than 0 or greater than or equals to list's size it will thorw IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: @Animal The Javadoc is telling the truth, since `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a sub-class of `IndexOutOfBoundException`.